# Parse html in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do i get output as below from give html page ?

```html
>html_sting='''<td class="status_icon" rowspan="2"><img alt="QUEUED" src="images/arts/status_QUEUED.png" style="border:none" title="QUEUED"/></td>

><td class="test"> v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200
 >     <div class="start">(04.02) 23:29</div>
>  <div class="end">~
 >       <span style="color:green"> () </span>
> </div>
></td>

><td>mcordeix</td>
><td>1614809</td>

><td><a href="?command=compoundinfo&amp;test_id=v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200 " onmouseover="Tip('compounds completed/running/queued')"target="_blank">0/0/0 of 0</a></td>
><td>high</td>
><td style="white-space:nowrap"><img class="pbar" src="images/arts/bar_green.gif" style="border-right:2px;border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#ffffff" width="1%"/><img class="pbar" src="images/arts/bar_gray.gif" width="99%"/></td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
><td colspan="4">
><!-- Florent Vial: this can be alway shown if admin=1 -->
><a href="?command=getrequest&amp;test_id=v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200" target="_blank">XML</a>
><a href="?command=getrequest&amp;test_id=v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200&amp;raw=1" target="_blank">Raw XML</a>
><a href="?command=compoundinfo&amp;test_id=v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200" target="_blank">CINFO</a>
></td>
><td></td>
><td><!-- <script type="text/javascript">DIVShowHideDetails('func:DoPrintArtsDetails')</script> --> </td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
><td></td>
'''
   EXpected Output:
-------
Status="QUEUED"
test=v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200
start=(04.02) 23:29
end=~
user=mcordeix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please read the [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of our FAQ.

> Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.

What have you tried to solve this problem so far?

---

Let's give you a start.

All you're gonna need are the [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) functions.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)

status = soup.find('img').get('alt')  # get 'alt' content of the first <img> tag.

# find the first <td> tag with a class="test", get its content, split it using spaces,
version = soup.find('td', class_='test').text.split()[0]  # and get the first substring
time_start = soup.find('div', class_='start').text
time_end = soup.find('div', class_='end').text
user = soup.find_all('td')[2].text  # get a third <td>'s content.

print status  # QUEUED
print version  # v1402beta_150127_1_OTM_TICKETS_dv_c_UID142307274200
print time_start  # (04.02) 23:29
print time_end  # ~  >        () >
print user  # mcordeix
```

That's just reading the [bs4's documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) for like 10 minutes and trying it yourself.
Just pop out the Python interpreter, assign the `html_string` variable, import the beautifulsoup library, and try.

I'm sure you could work out the problem left with the `time_end` content yourself. It's not that hard.